# How to bind multiple user controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have created the following User Control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TextBinder" ...>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ????}" />
</UserControl>
```

Now I am using my user control twice in my MainWindow. The MainWindow is then bound to my ViewModel (I set the DataContext). Now the problem is: how can I bind my user controls to the user_controlViewModel?

In my ViewModel, I have created two objects let's call them UC_1 and UC_2, they contain different texts and I would like to bind them to their respective user control in my MainWindow.

What should I put at ????

Note: please do not simplify mu TextBox to double textboxes in one usercontrol. This is not what I would like since in my real life example I have more stuff than textbox only and the usercontrol should be used multiple times in one view.

Thanks!

Comment: Define dependency property in you user control.

Comment: So your `MainWindow` has `DataContext` set to `ViewModel` if that's the case then your `<UserControl.DataContext="{Binding UC_1}"/>` then your `<TextBox Text="{Binding propertyOnYourUC_1}"/>` try that, without `DependencyProperty`. HTH

Answer (score 2):

i gave you a general answer:

within a "real(a usercontrol you wanna use with different viewmodels with different property names)" usercontrol you **bind just to your own DependencyProperties** and you do that with **ElementName or RelativeSource binding** and you should **never set the DataContext within a UserControl**.

```
 <UserControl x:Name="myRealUC" x:class="MyUserControl">
   <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=myRealUC, Path=MyOwnDPIDeclaredInMyUc, Path=TwoWay}"/>
 <UserControl>
```

if you do that you can easily use this Usercontrol in any view like:

```
<myControls:MyUserControl MyOwnDPIDeclaredInMyUc="{Binding MyPropertyInMyViewmodel}"/>
```

and for completeness: the Dependency Property

```
    public readonly static DependencyProperty MyOwnDPIDeclaredInMyUcProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "MyOwnDPIDeclaredInMyUc", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public bool MyOwnDPIDeclaredInMyUc
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyOwnDPIDeclaredInMyUcProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyOwnDPIDeclaredInMyUcProperty, value); }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats right, you need yo declare a dependency property in your UserControl:

```
public partial class TextBinder:UserControl
{

  public static readonly DependencyProperty textproperty = 
  DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(TextBinder));

  public string Text
  {
    get
    {
        return this.GetValue(textproperty) as string;
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetValue(textproperty,value);
    }
  }
}
```

And then, you can use your usercontrol in your window at this way:

```
<YourNamespace:TextBinder Text={Binding ViewModelProperty}/>
```